# OpenLayers, Geoserver, Postgis, GITHUB and content management

Tags: openlayers-2, postgresql, drupal

Im not sure if this is the right forum for this question.

I am working on a project to look into developing a prototype mapping applications for the agriculture industry. I am using asp classic, openlayers, geoserver and postgres for the application atm I plan on changing from asp classic to php soon.

Could  a CMS be used to manage page layouts, map layers styles, user profiles, user permissions etc in my current aplication.

Can GIT repository be used to store code, and manage code versioning used in the application?

I have no idea where to start. Has anyone got any advise or links to share. I have done some searching on the web but there is just some much to trawl through.
I do have both cartaro and drupal installed, but I can find any simple way to use them for my application. Here is a link`http://54.252.203.210/FARMWEB/FARMWEB2.0_DEMO_STEP3_PG.asp?farmid=354` to what I have developed so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really the right place, but you have touched on the fact that you're mapping - that may be good enough for some mods, but I doubt it.

### CMS

For most cases, a CMS is anything you want it to be - and has been known to [integrate with geospatial information](https://drupal.org/project/geo_gui).  I tend to stay away from CMS, however, since I frequently hit the wall in terms of performance and extensibility.  If I can offer any advice, it would be that your application should be coded in a way that is as platform independent as possible.  There's no telling when your framework provider will reach the end of their lifecycle.  Therefore, you should outline your code before you start to code - then look at whether or not you actually need a CMS, or if you just need an MVC framework.

### Git

If you're doing any quantity of coding, a repo is one of the first things you should start with.  As a general rule, commit and commit often.  There's no telling when you're going to break something.  Without a versioning system, Ctrl+Z can only do so much.  Atlassian has a great intro to git [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git).  They even provide free private repos on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) - but I personally use [GitHub](http://github.com).

As an aside, github recently introduced a display for geojson data: https://help.github.com/articles/mapping-geojson-files-on-github.  Personally, I think it's all an ooooh-aaaah factor, but meh.

Comment: Thanks Geoist, thanks for taking the time to explain your perspective on these two systems. Good point on platform dependency.